# cv2.VideoCapture isn't read video coming from frontend

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, flask, video-capture

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        vid = request.files['file']
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
        while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret,frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break

            do_something()

            k = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if k == 27:
                break
```

I am sending a video from frontend to flask server to process it. But when I run this code, this error shows up on line `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)`:

*TypeError: an integer is required (got type FileStorage)*

The video coming is converted in class *'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage'* and `cv2.VideoCapture` isn't accepting input as this class. What should I do?

I tried to save the video on local system using `vid.save('abc.webm')` and then read it using `cv2.VideoCapture` and it works perfectly. But I don't want to save it on system.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put a zero instead of vid and see how it works. (cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0))

Comment: Yes that is working. But I don't want to use the webcam feed, I want to process the video which got from frontend.

Comment: So you have 2 video input to your system?

Comment: VideoCapture can work with files and with streams and  with folders/images. If you have a custom type, it doesnt know how to work with that.

Comment: @MH304 no. I have only video input. I am recording stream using webcam on the frontend using javascript and then send that video to flask server on backend where I want to process that video using opencv. But I can't access the video using cv2.VideoCapture.

Comment: @Micka So can you suggest any method to convert 'werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage' to streamable format or in-memory file? I tried to convert it into 'io.BytesIO' but cv2.VideoCapture doesn't work with that too.

Comment: not sure about python. Maybe there's ffmpeg available, but I dont know much about flask. So no idea, tbh. Probably you'll have to stick to writing the file. If you are working with linux, you maybe can write to a RAM disk and load the file from there, which should be quite fast.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `.read()` to get the bytes from the FileStorage object.

```
vid = request.files['file'].read()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)
```